# Rounding numbers in ruby up or down to nearest 10 / 100 / 1000 in a different way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Short version:** a different way to "round" numbers to user-friendly values without .round/.floor/.ceil.

**Long boring version:** Imagine the following conversations between a salesperson and clients:

> Salesperson: how much would you pay for product X? Small timer: $15
>   SP: I can sell it to you at $50 ST: OK, I can live with that.

Had the salesperson said $100 the small timer would have said nah can’t afford it. And obviously he can’t just give it away for free because the salesperson isn’t a charity.

Then again with an average guy:

> Salesperson: how much would you pay for product X? Average guy: don’t
>   know...$120? SP: nah $200 is the minimum we’d sell for. AG: ok fine.

Then the big daddy comes in:

> Salesperson: how much would you like to spend today sir? Big daddy:
>   about $1200? SP: why not $1500? Big daddy: yeah let’s do $1500. SP: why not $1650? Big daddy: we might as well do $2000. SP: thank you for your business sir!

Yes, we do know who’s who, as in about how much money the customer may have, eg for a big guy we know he has around $2000-$5000 on him.

So I am looking for a way to round product prices in a smart but sensitive way as follows:

```
15 -> 50 #!
23 -> 50
51 -> 100
71 -> 100
109 -> 100
132 -> 150 
124 -> 150 #!
173 -> 200
399 -> 400
549 -> 500
1231 -> 1500 #!
2761 -> 3000 
3104 -> 3000
3249 -> 3500 #!
```

Basically round the prices up or down to make them user-friendly but without deviating that much from common sense...

```
class Price

    def initialize(s = 0) # possibly add customer “size”?
        @price = s
    end

    # operations
    def inc_to(x)
        @price = [@price, x].flatten.max
        self
    end

    def dec_to(x)
        @price = [@price, x].flatten.min
        self
    end

    def inc_with(x)
        @price+=x
        self
    end

    def dec_by(x)
        @price = @price - x
        self
    end

    def avg(x)
        arr = [@price, x]
        @price = arr.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / arr.size
        self
    end

    def round
        #@price = ?
        self
    end

    # getters
    def value
        @price
    end

    def to_i
        @price.to_i
    end

    def to_f
        @price.to_f
    end

end
```

I've tried writing this example class but can't seem to pull a nice .round method, will appreciate any input.

```
Price.new(15).inc_to(1000).dec_to(700).avg(100).inc_to(200).inc_to(400).dec_to(351).inc_with(48).value # .round.to_i
```

Comment: Thank you for downvoting, I’ve added some clarification as to why this is needed (use case). I shouldn’t have to explain why the round/ceil functions just won’t cut it.

Comment: The wording of your question is, well, horrible. Not only is the rounding criteria unclear, the first several paragraphs, which add nothing, are an irritating time-waster for the reader. If you are asked to write a code spec and begin it as you have done here, and fail to produce a complete and unambiguous statement of what is needed, you'll soon be looking for another job. btw, I'm told I have a great sense of humour, but there is nothing amusing in what you have written.

Comment: Thanks Cary. Was not trying to be funny or anything like that, was merely trying to explain where I’m comkng from and why I can’t use the already known methods. I’m sorry my particular style was not to your liking, it can happen to anyone, to my excuse it was 3AM over here and I was typing from a phone. Have a lovely week-end!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not possible to handle the input as you want with the generic rounding method because of contradictory rules (you want 51 to be *“rounded”* to 100 and others floored down.)

I would go with producing a hash or `Range` → `Price` pairs:

```
rounds = {
  (0..50) => 50,
  (51..110) => 100,
  (111..165) => 150,
  (166..220) => 200,
  ...
  (700..1200) => 1000,
  (1201..1600) => 1500,
  ...
  (4200..7000) => 5000      
}
```

and then just do `detect`:

```
rounds.detect { |range, _| range === price }.last
```

Comment: This is actually an awesome answer. It solves the need without putting togerther all sorts of algorithms or ML models (as one of my colleagues suggested at some point). Makes me remember about a guy who was laughed at for a similar solution to a similar problem, then everyone noticed he solved it with the least possible amount of code and his function beat all other benchmarks by a mile. Thank you sir!!

Comment: what in built methods could you use to round? I have a similar question